# Error using a trigger in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I made a Table using a Database in visual 2015 and in the table I have name, n1 , n2 , and avg. I made a insert button with 3 textboxes where I insert my name, number1 and number2 and when I press the button I want to save them in a table. If I use 4 textboxes (one for avg) it works, but I want to use a trigger. So.. I created a trigger >

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Table1]
FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table1
    SET avg = (N1+N2)/2
END
```

and here is my insert string

```
 string ins = "insert into Table1 values ('"; ins += textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";
```

and I get this error..

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I don't know what to do :(

Comment: What does your insert statement/stored procedure look like? That's the problem, not the trigger.

Comment: Also, I'd add a `where` clause to your update statement in your trigger so you are only updating the record for the `name` that was updated/inserted, instead of EVERY record in the table.

Comment: string ins = "insert into Table1 values ('"; ins += textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')"; @ganders

Comment: Can you add to your question so it's nicely formatted?

Comment: Specify the columns that you want to insert after your tablename, like this: insert into Medie (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3)

Comment: I don't think that trigger is going to do what you think it will do. Do you really want to recalculate the avg of every row each time you add a row?

Comment: It worked, ty ^^ @ganders

Comment: And before putting this code into a production environment, please read about SQL Injection Attacks. Parameterized queries are how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I still don't think we have all the information, but I'll give a crack at it...

The error message is from the insert statement, not from the trigger.

For your insert, I'd format it so you specifically state which values/columns will be inserted into the table.

It appears as though your average column is a non-nullable field, without a default constraint. So when you try to insert just the 3 values, it wants 4, because it HAS to have 4 (non-nullable). That's why it's throwing the error.

I'd structure your isnert like this:

```
insert
into Table (Col1, Col2, Col3)
values (val1, val2, val3)
```

Then, add a default constraint [then updated by trigger], OR, make the Average column nullable, so it can again then be updated via the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have a primary key column or another column you're not telling us about.

Either make the Primary Key column Auto-Increment, or make each column allow nulls or give each column a default value.

Also look up SQL Injection as your insert statement is susceptible to attacks.

There is also a problem with your syntax:

```
string ins = "insert into Table1 values ('"; ins += textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";
```

It should be

```
string ins = "insert into Table1 values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";
```